# How to add created date and modified date column in the python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to add created date and modified date column in the python pandas DataFrame ?
If I create a new row it should desplay created date column and if the row is modified then dataframe should display modified date column
where each of the row in dataframe have created date i.e. the row in that dataframe has been created or entered in the dataframe and have modified date i.e for each row if there any modification has been done then I want the modification date in that row.

I have number of column and want to add two new column in the dataframe where one shows the created date and other shows the modified date

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question you want to show when the row was modified if it is already present in your data frame and if it is a new entry you would wish to create a creation date.
If yes, you would need to append the new entries to your data frame so that you will have a blank creation date for the latest entries

```
df.loc[df['DateCreation'].notnull(), "DateModified"] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.loc[df['DateCreation'].isnull(), "DateCreation"] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```